# What's the difference between gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad and the -multiverse plugin?

Tags: plugins, gstreamer, multiverse

What is the difference between `gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad` and `gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse`?

Answer (score 3):

From the short description for `gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad`:

```
GStreamer Bad Plug-ins is a set of plug-ins that aren't up to par compared
 to the rest. They might be close to being good quality, but they're missing
 something - be it a good code review, some documentation, a set of tests, a
 real live maintainer, or some actual wide use.
```

The multiverse ones are in multiverse due to licensing issues.